# How to insert data to the DOM via local storage without duplicating the data each time

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am retrieving data from local storage and inserting it the DOM. 
The problem is that it is looping each time the local storage data and duplicating the data to the DOM when I call the function each time. I want to create an algorithm that prevents this. I want to only display the data only once in the DOM no matter how many times we loop over local storage.

I have tried numerous things. The recent is I tried to make a IF statement that loops over the local storage and fetches the current looped objects id and compares it to the DOM's id. If it is not similar, then place it to the DOM.
But it does not work.

```
export const displayIncome = (income) => {
 const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('income'));
 let length = data.length;
 for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {

  const query = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  const queryToArray = Array.from(query);

  if(queryToArray.forEach(el => 
  parseInt(el.getAttribute("href").split('#')[1]) !== income[i].id)) {
   const markup = `
       <div class="item" href="#${income[i].id}">
        <div class="item__time">
          ${income[i].date}
        </div>
        <div class="item__description">
          ${income[i].description}
        </div>
        <div class="item__value">
          ${income[i].value}
          <div class="item__delete">
            <div class="item__delete--btn"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
`;
    document.querySelector('.container').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);
 }
}
```

I expect to only get data to the DOM that has a unique ID.
But I am getting duplicates of the same data each time I loop that has the same ID

Comment: Do you mean something is wrong in `if` condition ?

Comment: `Array#filter` _or_ `if` condition inside `Array#forEach` could help!

Comment: In `if (queryToArray.forEach(...) !== income[i].id))` the *forEach* expression can be replaced with *undefined* since *forEach* always returns *undefined*, i.e. `if (income[i].id) !== undefined)`.

Comment: Hi Rayon. Sorry for the not making it clear enough. Yes the if statement is never false. It never filters out the duplicate ids. With this code parseInt(el.getAttribute("href").split('#')[1]) I get exactly the ids number as an integer. That should test the objects.id.